# WPF DataGrid SelectedCellsChanged event fires twice

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have subscribed via

```
_itemsGrid.SelectedCellsChanged += Handle_SelectedCellsChangedEvent;
```

to the WPF DataGrid SelectedCellsChanged event and when logging via

```
private void Handle_SelectedCellsChangedEvent (object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Logger.DoLogging("args.AddedCells.Count={0}, args.RemovedCells.Count={1}.", args.AddedCells.Count, args.RemovedCells.Count);
    ...
}
```

I see that sometimes for one row selection change there are two calls:

  1. AddedCells.Count = 4, RemovedCells.Count = 0

  2. AddedCells.Count = 0, RemovedCells.Count = 4

Now this behavior might be unhandy or unexpected, but is in itself no problem.
My real problem is that in certain conditions the data grid forgets to unselect the removed cells.
This means after the event handler are called and processed, the former selected cells are still visually selected.

My assumption is that this forgetting is related to a dialog that I'm displaying to the user.

Has anybody else seen the data grid "forgetting" to unselect cells?

Thanks
Frank

Answer (score 3):

The event not only encapsulates the action of notifying of cells being added to the selection (i.e. the [SelectedCells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcells.aspx)), but it also notifies of cells being removed from the selection. This allows you to take action on both or either selection change types.

I believe this corresponds with the fact that [NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.aspx) has a single Action. So to show a change in the SelectedCells collection of the grid, items need to be both added and removed. The notification of this addition and removal is separated into to distinct notifications since the event does not support showing them as one.

Comment: Hi Damian, thanks for your answer. I have however edited my question, because my original problem are not the 2 events but the data grid forgetting to unselect the removed cells.